# How to stop Visual Studio from replacing C# BCL types whatsoever with intrinsic counterparts

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When writing C# in Visual Studio 2017, I prefer some BCL types over their intrinsic counterparts where the latter confuses me.

For example when I combine a C++/CLI class library with a C# application and frequently switch between them within the IDE, I find it more comfortable to always use `String` instead of `string` in the C# part because `string` reminds me of the STL string type.

*(Disclosure: I am a dumb and clumsy person who relies heavily on such fool-proof mechanisms to write proper code.)*

My problem is that I cannot get VS to abide by my decision.
I turned off two automatic formatting options related to the preference of either BCL or intrinsic types, but the IDE seems to still replace `String` to `string` when typing in the following line (the second `String` is rewritten):

```
String[] foo = new String[] { "bar", "baz" };
```

How can I tell the IDE to *never* replace BCL types with intrinsic types, without disabling any other auto-formatting features?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DavidL I am sorry I did not clarify that the question is about the realtime code formatting feature in recent Visual Studio releases including VS2017. You should be able to reproduce the problem just by typing the line in question inside any sort of C# source code.

Comment: `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style->predefined type preferences` allows you to change this.

Comment: @mjwills I tried those options but it seems that they do not apply to some cases, including the one in the question, which includes `String[]` on the right hand side of the assignment.

Comment: I just typed in `String[] bob = new String[] { "a" };` and the IDE didn't change it. Do you have Resharper or something similar installed?

Comment: In all honesty though, you are fighting gravity here. The idiomatic C# style is to use the C# specific names. Do you have to? No? But if you don't, you make life harder for the next developer (and there **will** be another developer, unless you are immortal).

Comment: @mjwills No, actually I am using the VS2017 Express Edition so there is no way I can install anything.